# Combining SQL statements and including strings for time ranges

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm wanting to combine the following SQL statements so that I have all the results in one column rather than in 4 seperate ones:

```
select count(incnum) as counttenth3 from kincident where (to_char(reportdate,'hh24') between 0 and 2.59 or to_char(reportdate,'hh24') between 21 and 23.59 

select count(incnum) as counttenth2 from kincident where to_char(reportdate,'hh24') between 15 and 20.59

select count(incnum) as counttenth1 from kincident where to_char(reportdate,'hh24') between 9 and 14.59

select count(incnum) as counttenth0 from kincident  where to_char(reportdate,'hh24') between 3 and 8.59
```

The only difference is the time range given for each statement.
So I'm trying to combine them all into one to be in one column and I want a second column to include rows with given strings (not from the database)

E.g.

```
Timing    |  count of incidents
-----------------------------
morning   | 26
afternoon | 35
night     | 40
```

Comment: So you want to think about this in 2 steps - categories into your time ranges then group by the category

Comment: @ChrisMoutray That's what I'm having trouble with, I don't know how to assign a category to a time range. All I have is the individual 4 statements and each one is one of [morning,afternoon,night,past midnight]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this - untested since I generally write MS SQL :)

```
select 
    t.time_of_day, 
    count(t.time_of_day)
from 
(
    ---
    select
        case to_char(reportdate,'hh24')
            when between 15 and 20.59 then 'afternoon'
            when between 9 and 14.59 then 'morning'
            when between 3 and 8.59 then 'early-morning'
            else 'night' --when between 0 and 2.59 or to_char(reportdate,'hh24') between 21 and 23.59 
        end as time_of_day       
    from 
        kincident
) t
group by 
    t.time_of_day
```

Use a CASE statement to categories your time ranges, which I've put into a sub-query, but you could wrap in a view; as part of the outer query we group the time-of-day categories and count then in the outer select.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you want group by with a case statement:

```
select 
    case when to_char(reportdate,'hh24') between 3 and 8.59 then 'morning'
         when to_char(reportdate,'hh24') between 9 and 14.59 then 'noon'  
         when to_char(reportdate,'hh24') between 15 and 20.59 then 'afternoon'
         else 'night' end as range
   ,count(incnum)
from 
    kincident 
group by 
    case when to_char(reportdate,'hh24') between 3 and 8.59 then 'morning'
         when to_char(reportdate,'hh24') between 9 and 14.59 then 'noon'  
         when to_char(reportdate,'hh24') between 15 and 20.59 then 'afternoon'
         else 'night' end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd redo this to use a lookup table of time ranges to join against. Add a TIME_CATEGORY table that has 24 rows, mapping each hour to a "time category". Why? It becomes reusable through other parts of your system / queries, and also allows you to implement a time based rules engine with central control from a single place. (Once you start down the route of writing case statements, you often end up repeating yourself everywhere).

```
create table time_category(
   hour integer primary key,
   category varchar2(20)
) organization index;

-- populate categories
begin
  for i in 0 .. 2 loop
    insert into time_category values(i, 'Night');
  end loop;
  for i in 3 .. 8 loop
    insert into time_category values(i, 'Morning');
  end loop;
  for i in 9 .. 14 loop
    insert into time_category values(i, 'Noon');
  end loop;
  for i in 15 .. 20 loop
    insert into time_category values(i, 'Afternoon');
  end loop;
  for i in 21 .. 23 loop
    insert into time_category values(i, 'Night');
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Then your query becomes:

```
-- Join incident table to time categories by hour of reportdate

select category as Timing, count(1) as "Count of incidents"
   from kincident i join time_category tc on extract(hour from i.reportdate) = tc.hour
   group by category
;
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Jaugar Chang's answer:
1.) To get the constant values just use a string-constant instead of a cloumn name.
2.) you can use `union` to join the queries into one.

So it'll look like this:

```
select 'night', count(incnum) as incidentcout from kincident where (to_char(reportdate,'hh24') between 0 and 2.59 or to_char(reportdate,'hh24') between 21 and 23.59 
union
select 'afternoon', count(incnum) as incidentcout  from kincident where to_char(reportdate,'hh24') between 15 and 20.59
union
select 'noon', count(incnum) as incidentcout  as counttenth1 from kincident where to_char(reportdate,'hh24') between 9 and 14.59
union
select 'morning', count(incnum) as incidentcout from kincident  where to_char(reportdate,'hh24') between 3 and 8.59
```